# I need to rename the key in an array php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to rename the key in an array php:
I need to change the key name to this, menu_link_content sub array:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [menu_link_id] => 1
                [menu_id] => 2
                [parent_id] => 0
                [page_id] => 1
                [menu_link_type] => page
                [menu_link_order] => 
                [menu_link_url] => 
                [menu_link_class] => 
                [menu_link_date] => 2013-10-08 14:23:16
                [page_path] => 
                [menu_link_content] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [menu_link_content_id] => 1
                                [menu_link_id] => 1
                                [lang_id] => 1
                                [menu_link_text] => home
                                [menu_link_title] => 
                                [lang_flag] => italia.jpg
                                [lang_name] => Italiano
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [menu_link_content_id] => 3
                                [menu_link_id] => 1
                                [lang_id] => 3
                                [menu_link_text] => home inglese
                                [menu_link_title] => 
                                [lang_flag] => inghilterra.jpg
                                [lang_name] => Inglese
                            )

                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [menu_link_id] => 2
                [menu_id] => 2
                [parent_id] => 0
                [page_id] => 2
                [menu_link_type] => page
                [menu_link_order] => 
                [menu_link_url] => 
                [menu_link_class] => 
                [menu_link_date] => 2013-10-08 14:23:19
                [page_path] => 
                [menu_link_content] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [menu_link_content_id] => 2
                                [menu_link_id] => 2
                                [lang_id] => 1
                                [menu_link_text] => prova
                                [menu_link_title] => 
                                [lang_flag] => italia.jpg
                                [lang_name] => Italiano
                            )

                    )

            )

    )
```

I would like to have this result:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [menu_link_id] => 1
                    [menu_id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [page_id] => 1
                    [menu_link_type] => page
                    [menu_link_order] => 
                    [menu_link_url] => 
                    [menu_link_class] => 
                    [menu_link_date] => 2013-10-08 14:23:16
                    [page_path] => 
                    [menu_link_content] => Array
                        (
                            [this_lang_id in this case is 1] => Array
                                (
                                    [menu_link_content_id] => 1
                                    [menu_link_id] => 1
                                    [lang_id] => 1
                                    [menu_link_text] => home
                                    [menu_link_title] => 
                                    [lang_flag] => italia.jpg
                                    [lang_name] => Italiano
                                )

                            [this_lang_id in this case is 3] => Array
                                (
                                    [menu_link_content_id] => 3
                                    [menu_link_id] => 1
                                    [lang_id] => 3
                                    [menu_link_text] => home inglese
                                    [menu_link_title] => 
                                    [lang_flag] => inghilterra.jpg
                                    [lang_name] => Inglese
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [menu_link_id] => 2
                    [menu_id] => 2
                    [parent_id] => 0
                    [page_id] => 2
                    [menu_link_type] => page
                    [menu_link_order] => 
                    [menu_link_url] => 
                    [menu_link_class] => 
                    [menu_link_date] => 2013-10-08 14:23:19
                    [page_path] => 
                    [menu_link_content] => Array
                        (
                            [this_lang_id in this case is 1] => Array
                                (
                                    [menu_link_content_id] => 2
                                    [menu_link_id] => 2
                                    [lang_id] => 1
                                    [menu_link_text] => prova
                                    [menu_link_title] => 
                                    [lang_flag] => italia.jpg
                                    [lang_name] => Italiano
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

then I do not want this [menu_link_content] [0] but I want this [menu_link_content] [1] because one is the lang_id contained in that [menu_link_content] array.

how should I do?

***mod***
This is my function:

```
$this->query('
    SELECT c.*, l.lang_flag, l.lang_name
    FROM tb_menu_link_content AS c
    INNER JOIN tb_lang AS l
    ON l.lang_id = c.lang_id
    WHERE c.menu_link_id = "'.$menu_link['menu_link_id'].'"
');
$menu_link_content = $this->fetch_assoc_all();
foreach($menu_link_content as $key => $value){
    $lang_id = $value['lang_id'];
    $new_array[$lang_id] = $value;
}
$menu_link_content = array('menu_link_content'=>$new_array);
$array[] = array_merge($menu_link, $menu_link_content);
```

works well but duplicates the language that there is on the second sub array [menu_link_content]
The lang_id 3 does not exist in the second [menu_link_content]

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [menu_link_id] => 1
            [menu_id] => 2
            [parent_id] => 0
            [page_id] => 1
            [menu_link_type] => page
            [menu_link_order] => 
            [menu_link_url] => 
            [menu_link_class] => 
            [menu_link_date] => 2013-10-08 14:23:16
            [page_path] => 
            [menu_link_content] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [menu_link_content_id] => 1
                            [menu_link_id] => 1
                            [lang_id] => 1
                            [menu_link_text] => home
                            [menu_link_title] => 
                            [lang_flag] => italia.jpg
                            [lang_name] => Italiano
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [menu_link_content_id] => 3
                            [menu_link_id] => 1
                            [lang_id] => 3
                            [menu_link_text] => home inglese
                            [menu_link_title] => 
                            [lang_flag] => inghilterra.jpg
                            [lang_name] => Inglese
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [menu_link_id] => 2
            [menu_id] => 2
            [parent_id] => 0
            [page_id] => 2
            [menu_link_type] => page
            [menu_link_order] => 
            [menu_link_url] => 
            [menu_link_class] => 
            [menu_link_date] => 2013-10-08 14:23:19
            [page_path] => 
            [menu_link_content] => Array
                (
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [menu_link_content_id] => 2
                            [menu_link_id] => 2
                            [lang_id] => 1
                            [menu_link_text] => prova
                            [menu_link_title] => 
                            [lang_flag] => italia.jpg
                            [lang_name] => Italiano
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [menu_link_content_id] => 3
                            [menu_link_id] => 1
                            [lang_id] => 3
                            [menu_link_text] => home inglese
                            [menu_link_title] => 
                            [lang_flag] => inghilterra.jpg
                            [lang_name] => Inglese
                        )

                )

        )
  )
```

my problem is this:
I have this array $ menu and I have an array $ languages

I have to create a function that creates for each language found:

```
<input type="text" name="menu_link_text[$language['lang_id']]" value="$menu['menu_link_text'][$language['lang_id']">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the name of the key of a given index in a created array. I won't give you the code for your solution but you would have to create a new array by iterating over your existing one and naming the keys in you new array as you see fit while drawing values from the existing array that you are iterating over.
To not have your data start at the key *0* you just make sure you manually enter *1* as your first key and keep going.

As long as the key in your "new" array don't collide with the names of keys in your existing array you can reuse that array and insert the new values and un-setting the old ones. But that can get messy and hard to debug.

But to change the name of the key *foo_id* to *id* you could do something like

```
foreach ( $array as $key => $value )
{
  $array[$key] ['id'] = $array[$key] ['foo_id'];
  unset($array[$key]['foo_id']);
}
```

But as I said... It can get pretty messy. Especially with multidimensional arrays ;)

Comment: my problem is this:
I have this array $ menu and I have an array $ languages

I have to create a function:
for each language dound creates a
<input type="text" name="menu_link_text[$language['lang_id']]" value="$menu['menu_link_text'][$language['lang_id']">

Answer (score 0):

Let's call your original array variable as `$my_array`.

```
foreach($my_array as $idx => $value) {
    // load the 'menu_link_content'
    $menu_link_content = $value['menu_link_content'];
    // prepare a new placeholder
    $new_menu_link_content = [];
    // iterate through $menu_link_content
    foreach($menu_link_content as $item) {
        // remap items
        $id = $item['menu_link_content_id' ];
        $new_menu_link_content[ $id ] = $item;
    }
    // replacing 'menu_link_content'
    $my_array[$idx]['menu_link_content'] = $new_menu_link_content;
}
```

Comment: ok sorry i have update my question now work with this
foreach($menu_link_content as $key => $value){
$lang_id = $value['lang_id'];
$new_array[$lang_id] = $value;
}
but there is a lang_id wrong in a second [menu_link_content]